# Is it natural to say "buy some bread as my breakfast and have it"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I just talked with a friend about my routine, I said

> On the way to subway station, I buy some bread as my breakfast and **have it** on the subway because I'm so busy that I don't have time to eat, neither at home nor at work.

An alternative might be

> ... I buy some bread as my breakfast and **eat it** ...

Which one is more common? Are there any other ways more natural that could be used there to convey the idea?

Answer (score -1):

When you buy things, you might have a purpose in mind **for** which they would be used.

It would be more natural to say:

> On the way to the subway station, I buy some bread **for** my breakfast.

or simply

> On the way to the subway station, I buy some bread for breakfast.

It is understood that it is your breakfast so you don't have to modify it with "my".

It is usual to say `have breakfast`.  One doesn't say usually say `have bread` such as "have bread on the subway", but one would say 'have bread **for** breakfast'.  It is more usual to have a soda or a drink, but one doesn't say "have **a** bread".   One usually **eats** bread.

Breakfast does somewhat imply sitting down for a meal.   In the context that you are describing, I wouldn't say you are having breakfast, but rather, `wolfing down breakfast` as is common in the American way.

It is correct point out it is natural to use a construction like "I have bread all the time." or "I have bread everyday." or "I have bread in the refrigerator."  Sitting at a table, it seems natural to ask a guest "Would you care for some bread?"  Or "Have a slice of bread?"

Comment: You can "have bread for breakfast".

Comment: I think the answer misses the point that the friend **has it on the subway** because s/he's so busy. And yes, in context, it sounds perfectly natural.

Comment: I _have bread_ all the time. That's a perfectly natural thing to say - and no more or less natural than having a soda/drink.